# How to ensure sequence of fields in mysql query always remains constant

Tags: mysql

I am using a "select" statement in mysql with a number of computed fields. It is essential that  the sequence of fields always remains same. Is there a way to ensure the sequence

Comment: It should always be the sequence that you're using in your statement, no? That would never change, would it?

Comment: That was my understanding as well but it has been observed that sequence of columns changes at times

Comment: By whom, where? Can you point to a source that makes that claim?

Comment: i think you want see the sequence of fields with same value. if my guess is true, what's that value ? you can simply use where statement in your select with that value to get specify sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of fields always will remain the same as your SELECT
for example if you

```
SELECT col1,col2
```

It will always select col1 as the first field and col2 as the second field.

If you're worried about sequence of rows within columns then you should use the `ORDER BY some_column`